# How can I repair a kit lens with a stuck auto/manual focus mode switch?

Tags: lens, nikon, autofocus, troubleshooting, kit-lens

Recently got a Nikon D5100. After a few days I realized that I can't focus in manual mode. The auto-manual (A-M) switch on the lens seems to be the issue (I have to press the switch hard to manually adjust the lens).

Any idea if the switch can be changed or is the whole lens required to be changed. The camera is working fine in Autofocus Mode.

Comment: Are you saying the A-M switch, it is difficult to switch it from A to M?

Comment: The switch can be toggled from 'A' to 'M' position but I guess its half broken ......so maybe does not get locked there......or the contact isn't making ....at 'M' position. Though if i hold it hard against the 'M' position am able to freely focus the lens.

Comment: Further, it is the kit lens

Answer (score 1):

The lens is broken - if it is under warranty get it to a Nikon service center (or maybe the place you bought it from) to be repaired or replaced.

If the lens isn't under warranty then you can often get a used kit lens for less than the repair cost (because of all the people buying the kit and then upgrading the lens)

Answer (score 0):

you must move that A-M switch on your 18-55 mm lens in order to shift from Autofocus to manual focus. There is no other way around with the excellent 18-55mm lens.

This does not mean it is a bad lens. It is only ergonomically lacking instant manual focus override. Otherwise, this lens is sharp, sharp, sharp even at the corners. It is among Nikon's 10 best lenses ever! Read more about it [here](http://www.kenrockwell.com/nikon/10-best.htm).

If you want instant manual focus override you should look for Nikkor lenses that have an "M/A-M" switch. This means, if your lens is in "M/A" mode, you can just turn the focus ring if you are not satisfied with autofocus. Example may include the excellent Nikkor 50mm f/1.8 G which I already own.

As for now, I must say, there's no problem with your 18-55mm. Just grab it and shoot!

And if you're not happy about its autofocus, turn on the live view, switch to "M" mode of the lens, zoom in the live view and focus until you get your focus sharp! That's done the trick for me for about a year. You can view one of my photos with the same camera and the same lens [here](http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10152364307025526&l=fb3e369386)

Comment: Nice shot there Rachcha!